# How can I move a database from one server to another? Completely

Tags: mysql, database, dump

I'm transferring complete database from online server to localhost server.

But all records are not transferring. Is there any way to transfer complete data with same rows .

I tried via Navicat, export and import single tables, import and export .sql and gzip but all result are different

My Hosting is Shared.
Software on localhost Xamp

Comment: How are they different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result is not missing probably your mysql tables on innodb click any table and see how many rows you are seeing .:) inno db now give the exact result

Answer (score 1):

You can try **mysqldump**.

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u user -pPassWord --skip-triggers --single-transaction --complete-insert --extended-insert --quote-names --disable-keys dataBaseName > DUMP_dataBaseName.sql
```

then move you file DUMP_dataBaseName.sql to your localhost, and:

```
mysql -hHost -uUser -pPass -DBase < DUMP_dataBaseName.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I have run into countless times when moving WordPress sites are special characters (specifically single quotes and double quotes).  The database will export fine, but upon import, it breaks at an "illegal" quote.  My workflow now consists of exporting the database, running a find and replace on the sql file to filter out the offending characters, and then importing.

Without knowing more about your specific situation, that's just something I would look into.